# How to create view of unloaded Redshift CSV object in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have data file that was unloaded from Redshift in CSV format, next I would like to create a view in `SnowFlake` so that I can copy the data into Snowflake VIEW. So far from documentation located [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html) I have created below below code and not sure how to proceed from there.
Will the below code load the data ?

Note: I have external stage created that points to S3 bucket.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view(col1,col2) AS SELECT * FROM external_s3_bucket;
```

Comment: You're going to want to look at External Tables rather than views. This will allow you to directly query your S3 bucket using a Snowflake object: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-intro.html#amazon-s3